# ListView in XML file not being picked up

Tags: android, xml, listview

Problems trying to display data from a DB to a listview using a custom cursor adapter. I think I have traced the issue to not being able to 'find' my listview element from the xml file.

In my XML file, I have this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="7" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have this in my main onCreate for my activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_trip_display);
.... // other code
tripList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

But that last line produces a ***'list cannot be resolved or is not a field'*** error in Eclipse.

If I add 'android' in there:

```
tripList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

it compiles OK but then I get a null entry for the variable 'tripList' which causes other NPE errors.

Any ideas?

EDIT: ok, I think my problem is my cursor adapter - will post a new question. Thank you all for looking...

Comment: Clean your project and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ListView` id is `android:id=@android:id/list"` then no need to defined

```
tripList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

and your `Activity` must Extends `ListActivity` and also no need to add `setContentView()` as **@AndroidWarrior's** comment

and if your `ListView` id is  `android:id="@+id/list"` then initialized your `ListView` with

```
tripList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Go to this for more Demos http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @Simple Plan If his `Activity` extends `ListActivity` then he probably wouldn't need a XML at all, in addition to that `setContentView()` will also not be required

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:id="@+id/android:list"` use `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: Tried that - app crashes with 'Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this in your coding

```
tripList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

then your class must be extends with `ListActivity`.

and change in your xml for `ListView` id like

```
 android:id="@+id/android:list"
```

to

```
 android:id ="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: I do extend ListActivity - if I use android.R.id.list, what happens is that my listView does get created BUT the bindView in my custom cursor adapter is not being called, so no data gets displayed. I think I'll post a new question along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with  **android:id="@+id/android:list"** replace with this

**android:id="@+id/list"**  and extend your application to Activity is enough.

**ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);**

accept ans if problem solved.

Comment: Tried that - app crashes with 'Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: oh then try to extend ListActivity @Nelmo

Comment: can you post the log what exactly it returning and high light the line number for the error @Nelmo